# Запятая в обороте с ''как"

Tags: пунктуация

*Светильник может использоваться, как настольная лампа.*

Нужна ли в этом предложении запятая?

Answer (score 4):

Запятая в вашем примере не нужна, оборот ***с как*** имеет значение "в качестве".